# Endnotes in Word - unwanted hard return symbol

Tags: microsoft-word

The hard return symbol at the top of each page does not show up on my regular text pages, only on the endnote pages. I have tried deleting. It doesn't work. I have looked at the format drop-down, but it doesn't address this.

I am trying to align the first lines of every page and this interferes. I read online about the separator possibly being the problem, but I can't find the separator or how to see the separator or how to choose a separator. My software is up to date.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried deleting. It doesn't work." What does "it does work" mean, exactly? If the carriage return in the header? Maybe some screencaps may clarify the problem.